# Kotlin equivalent to C# Task.WhenAll

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Is there a Kotlin Equivalent of C#'s [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

I came up with the code below, but I wonder if it is possible to write `whenAll` so that it only suspends once.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    println("Start")
    val serviceA = KotlinServiceA()
    val serviceB = KotlinServiceB()

    val deferredA = async(CommonPool) { serviceA.operationA() }
    val deferredB = async(CommonPool) { serviceB.operationB() }

    var tasks = arrayOf(deferredA, deferredB)
    tasks.whenAll()

    println("End")
}

suspend fun Array<Deferred<Unit>>.whenAll() : Unit {
    for (task in this) {
        task.await()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `awaitAll()` function that does the job.

```
val deferredArray: Array<Deferred<Unit>>  =  arrayOf()
val awaitAllArray = awaitAll(*deferredArray)
```

If you work with `Collection` then you can use the `awaitAll()` extension function

```
val deferredList: List<Deferred<Unit>>  =  listOf()
val awaitAllList = deferredList.awaitAll()
```

Comment: [Docs for `awaitAll`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/await-all.html)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html